# Possible to change background-color according to nested level?

Tags: css

I have an ordered list that can potentially have an infinite amount of nested lists. I'm looking to dynamically change the `background-color` of each nested list so that it progressively gets darker, making the grouping of each list much easier to understand.

So I have this basic structure (that can continue infinitely):

```
<ol class="top-level-list">
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <ol>
                    <li></li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Right now, I can accomplish this using something like this:

```
.top-level-list li ol li ol li {
    background: #D4D4D4;
}

.top-level-list li ol li ol li ol li{
    background: #C7C7C7;
}
```

That gives me what I want, but it is limited in how many levels I can use and each level adds more and more data to my CSS file, resulting in longer load times.

Is there a way to dynamically set the color with a single selector? I know CSS3 has added some new CSS selector tricks, but I can't find anything documenting something like this. Nor can I find a way to make a value in the selector correspond to the selector itself.

Comment: It's hard to believe a few css rules could impact your load time significantly, but if you're really concerned about it, omit the 'ol' from the selector -- they're not needed.

Comment: Have you tried using javascript to change the css property ? It wouldn't be too hard to just get the background and add a few to the hex value to programatically generate the colors.

Comment: How much `darker` next `li` should be? these kind of calculations needs JavaScript.

Comment: @HashemQolami That's what I figured, but I wanted to be sure. I wasn't sure if CSS3 had added any features that could accomplish this on its own. I can resort to JS if needed, obviously. I just thought it would be better if it could be done in pure CSS

Comment: The only way I know is what @Tim mentioned.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sort of. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but by using `rgba` for a `background-color` you can do a pretty decent simulation, I think. http://jsfiddle.net/jRdQC/

```
.top-level-list ol {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

The background colors 'layer' and therefore get darker as you go.

Comment: And it would be better to set a default `background-color: white` on the parent element `.top-level-list`.

Comment: This is elegant. Won't work in my case because each OL also has a background-color, but I could see about reworking the GUI a bit to rid myself of that. Regardless, fantastic idea. +1 from me

Comment: I reworked the UI a bit to remove the background on the OLs and the end-result is exactly what I had hoped for. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: Thanks. "Nice answer" from me. :^ )

Answer (score 3):

You could parse the tree with javascript to avoid the CSS burden. You will first need a function for color luminance:

```
function luminance(hex, lum) {
    // validate hex string
    hex = String(hex).replace(/[^0-9a-f]/gi, '');
    if (hex.length < 6) {
        hex = hex[0]+hex[0]+hex[1]+hex[1]+hex[2]+hex[2];
    }
    lum = lum || 0;
    // convert to decimal and change luminosity
    var rgb = "#", c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        c = parseInt(hex.substr(i*2,2), 16);
        c = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(0, c + (c * lum)), 255)).toString(16);
        rgb += ("00"+c).substr(c.length);
    }
    return rgb;
}
```

And then you would have to apply a darker color based on the nested level.

```
var color = '#efefef';

// You could also get the styled color by using:
// var color = $('.class-goes-here').css('background-color');

$('ol').each(function() {
    var depth = $(this).parents('ol').length;
    var darken_ratio = depth * .1;

    var darker_color = luminance(color, -darken_ratio);

    $(this).css('background-color', darker_color);
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dDUaF/1/

You can make the color darker by increasing the decimal in the darken_ratio variable. This will also work with any color in hex. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/dDUaF/4/

Comment: This works pretty well. It does exactly what I need it to, but some of the lists can get pretty deep and very large so I will stray away from JS methods when possible. Thanks for the answer, I can see other instances this may be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [another possible approach](https://jsfiddle.net/jxvgsba3/123/), that I went with, now that we can use `calc` and `var` in CSS.  Haven't tested in IE or Safari, but looks like it works in Firefox, and up to 15 levels in Chrome (seems like that may be an implementation problem).

- Does not use Javascript
- Does not require that elements to modify have transparency between them
- Allows for using the variable for other things like changing the hue (see commented line), borders, text, etc.

  ```
    :root {
      --levelCount1: 0;
      --levelCount2: 0;
    }

    ol {
      padding: 1em;

      --levelCount1: calc(var(--levelCount2) + 1);
    }

    li {
      border: 1px solid blue;

      --levelCount2: calc(var(--levelCount1));
      /* provides fallback for once if/when vars are no longer usable */
      background-color: hsl(20, 40%, 90%);
      background-color: hsl(200, 40%, calc(90% - ((var(--levelCount1) * 4) * 1%)));
      /*background-color: hsl(calc(var(--levelCount1) * 208), 40%, calc(90% - ((var(--levelCount1) * 4) * 1%))); */
    }
  ```